# How do I add a sub-menu item to a menu item using dojo dijit/form/DropDownButton?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, menuitem

I have created a Dojo DropDownButton using `dijit/form/DropDownButton` and created MenuItems using `dijit/MenuItem`. I am trying to create sub-menu items for the MenuItems so that the options are organized nicely and the user can have sub options to select from.
Is there any way to do this so that the dropdown options look like this:

```
    Vegetables
       Carrots
       Potatoes
       Tomatoes
    Fruits
       Apples
       Oranges
```

instead of this (what I currently have):

```
    Vegetables
    Carrots
    Potatoes
    Tomatoes
    Fruits
    Apples
    Oranges
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vegetables and Fruits should be `dijit/PopupMenuItem`s and each one should contain a `dijit/Menu` and the menu should have the corresponding `dijit/MenuItem`s.

The declarative menu example demonstrates it.  In your case, the only difference is that instead of a context menu, the top level menu is a `dijit/DropDownMenu`.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Menu.html#declarative-markup